# Sum of longest string of non-zero values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing the daily rainfall values at 76 stations from 1964-2013. Each row is a different month for a particular station. Here is a snippet of the dataframe-

```
 Station     Year Month Days 1   2   3  4 5   6  7  8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18  19 20 21 22 23  24 25 26 27 28 29  30  31
USC00020750 1964     1   31 0   0   0  0 0   0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  25  0 23 51 36   0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
USC00020750 1964     2   29 0   0   0  0 0   0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  48  0  0  0  3   0  0  0  0  0  0 Inf Inf
USC00020750 1964     3   31 0  46  51  0 0  36 41 46 0  0  0  0 43  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0 53 99 140 36  0  0  0  0   0   0
USC00020750 1964     4   30 5  69  23 30 0  18  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  33 13  0  0  0 15   0 Inf
USC00020750 1964     5   31 0   0   0  0 0   0 43  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0 51  8  0  0   0   0
USC00020750 1964     6   30 0   0   0  0 0   0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0 38  0  0   0 Inf
USC00020750 1964     7   31 0   0   0  0 0   0  0  0 0  0  0  0 41  0 13 13  0  0   0  0  8 51  0  71  0 10  0  0 20 165  25
USC00020750 1964     8   31 8  30 137  0 0   5 89  0 0  0 18 64  5  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0 76  0  0  0   0   0
USC00020750 1964     9   30 0   0   0  0 0 119  0  0 0  0  0  0  0 41 25  0  0  0   0  0 25  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0   0 Inf
USC00020750 1964    10   31 0   0   0  0 0   0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
USC00020750 1964    11   30 0   5   0  0 0   0  0  0 0  0 91  0  0  0 36 94  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0   0 Inf
USC00020750 1964    12   31 0 107  20  0 0   0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 79 152  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
```

...

```
Station Year Month Days  1  2   3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28  29  30  31
USW00093129 2013    10   31  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0 43 15  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 41   3   8   0
USW00093129 2013    11   30  0  0   0 23  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  3 79 18 20  0  0  0  0  0   0   0 Inf
USW00093129 2013    12   31  0  0 175 33  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  5 15  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0
```

I am trying to find the length of the longest stretch of non-zero rainfall values for each row and the total rainfall in that stretch. The easiest way to find the length of the longest stretch would be to convert the dataframe to 0s and 1s, use rle and apply `max(y$lengths[y$values!=0])` along each row. But how do I find the sum of the values? 
Thanks for helping out, in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using `apply` with `MARGIN=1`.

Comment: @akrun Yes, I have used the MARGIN argument to apply the rle function to each row. But I don't know how to find the sum of the longest stretch of non-zero values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly a one-liner, but this works :

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,check.names=FALSE,text=
"Station     Year Month Days 1   2   3  4 5   6  7  8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18  19 20 21 22 23  24 25 26 27 28 29  30  31
USC00020750 1964     1   31 0   0   0  0 0   0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  25  0 23 51 36   0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
USC00020750 1964     2   29 0   0   0  0 0   0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  48  0  0  0  3   0  0  0  0  0  0 Inf Inf
USC00020750 1964     3   31 0  46  51  0 0  36 41 46 0  0  0  0 43  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0 53 99 140 36  0  0  0  0   0   0
USC00020750 1964     4   30 5  69  23 30 0  18  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  33 13  0  0  0 15   0 Inf
USC00020750 1964     5   31 0   0   0  0 0   0 43  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0 51  8  0  0   0   0
USC00020750 1964     6   30 0   0   0  0 0   0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0 38  0  0   0 Inf
USC00020750 1964     7   31 0   0   0  0 0   0  0  0 0  0  0  0 41  0 13 13  0  0   0  0  8 51  0  71  0 10  0  0 20 165  25
USC00020750 1964     8   31 8  30 137  0 0   5 89  0 0  0 18 64  5  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0 76  0  0  0   0   0
USC00020750 1964     9   30 0   0   0  0 0 119  0  0 0  0  0  0  0 41 25  0  0  0   0  0 25  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0   0 Inf
USC00020750 1964    10   31 0   0   0  0 0   0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
USC00020750 1964    11   30 0   5   0  0 0   0  0  0 0  0 91  0  0  0 36 94  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0   0 Inf
USC00020750 1964    12   31 0 107  20  0 0   0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 79 152  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0")

res <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(r){
  monthDays <- df[r,'Days']
  rain <- as.numeric(df[r,(1:monthDays) + 4])
  enc <- rle(rain > 0)
  if(all(!enc$values))
    return(c(0,0))
  len <- enc$lengths
  len[!enc$values] <- 0
  max.idx <- which.max(len)
  lastIdx <- cumsum(enc$lengths)[max.idx]
  firstIdx <- lastIdx - enc$lengths[max.idx] + 1
  tot <- sum(rain[firstIdx:lastIdx])
  stretch <- lastIdx - firstIdx + 1
  return(c(stretch,tot))  
})
columnsToAdd <- do.call(rbind,res)
colnames(columnsToAdd) <- c('StretchLen','StretchRain')

df2 <- cbind(df,columnsToAdd)
```

Result :

```
# We print the result without months values for better readability
> df2[,-(5:35)]
       Station Year Month Days StretchLen StretchRain
1  USC00020750 1964     1   31          3         110
2  USC00020750 1964     2   29          1          48
3  USC00020750 1964     3   31          4         328
4  USC00020750 1964     4   30          4         127
5  USC00020750 1964     5   31          2          59
6  USC00020750 1964     6   30          1          38
7  USC00020750 1964     7   31          3         210
8  USC00020750 1964     8   31          3         175
9  USC00020750 1964     9   30          2          66
10 USC00020750 1964    10   31          0           0
11 USC00020750 1964    11   30          2         130
12 USC00020750 1964    12   31          2         127
```

BTW, if you want to stick with apply, it would be like this :

```
columnsToAdd <- 
t(apply(df[,-(1:3)],MARGIN=1,function(r){
  monthDays <- r[1]
  rain <- as.numeric(r[-1])
  enc <- rle(rain > 0)
  if(all(!enc$values))
    return(c(0,0))
  len <- enc$lengths
  len[!enc$values] <- 0
  max.idx <- which.max(len)
  lastIdx <- cumsum(enc$lengths)[max.idx]
  firstIdx <- lastIdx - enc$lengths[max.idx] + 1
  tot <- sum(rain[firstIdx:lastIdx])
  stretch <- lastIdx - firstIdx + 1
  return(c(stretch,tot))  
}))

colnames(columnsToAdd) <- c('StretchLen','StretchRain')

df2 <- cbind(df,columnsToAdd)
```

I don't like using `apply` on data.frame's since it has been created for matrices and so it coerces the columns to the same type before calling the function (hence if you work on columns of different types you need to be careful).

Comment: Handled case when all days have zero rain

Comment: No prob, I've added also a solution using apply (and a reason why to not use it for data.frame's)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution with dplyr/tidyr

```
data %>%
  gather(day, rain, -Station, -Year, -Month, -Days) %>%
  arrange(Station, Year, Month, day) %>%
  group_by(Station, Year, Month) %>%
  mutate(previous_rain = lag(rain)) %>%
  filter(!(rain %in% c(0, Inf))) %>%
  mutate(storm = cumsum(previous_rain %in% c(0, NA))) %>%
  group_by(Station, Year, Month, storm) %>%
  summarize(total_rain = sum(rain),
            number_of_days = n(),
            start_day = first(day),
            end_day = last(day)) %>%
  arrange(desc(number_of_days)) %>%
  slice(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another take at it, where I've used the `rle()` function to find run lengths.  It's protracted but primarily to make it clear what is happening - you could shorten it easily.

```
raindf <- 
    tmp <- read.table(textConnection(" Station     Year Month Days 1   2   3  4 5   6  7  8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18  19 20 21 22 23  24 25 26 27 28 29  30  31
USC00020750 1964     1   31 0   0   0  0 0   0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  25  0 23 51 36   0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
           USC00020750 1964     2   29 0   0   0  0 0   0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  48  0  0  0  3   0  0  0  0  0  0 Inf Inf
           USC00020750 1964     3   31 0  46  51  0 0  36 41 46 0  0  0  0 43  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0 53 99 140 36  0  0  0  0   0   0
           USC00020750 1964     4   30 5  69  23 30 0  18  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  33 13  0  0  0 15   0 Inf
           USC00020750 1964     5   31 0   0   0  0 0   0 43  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0 51  8  0  0   0   0
           USC00020750 1964     6   30 0   0   0  0 0   0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0 38  0  0   0 Inf
           USC00020750 1964     7   31 0   0   0  0 0   0  0  0 0  0  0  0 41  0 13 13  0  0   0  0  8 51  0  71  0 10  0  0 20 165  25
           USC00020750 1964     8   31 8  30 137  0 0   5 89  0 0  0 18 64  5  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0 76  0  0  0   0   0
           USC00020750 1964     9   30 0   0   0  0 0 119  0  0 0  0  0  0  0 41 25  0  0  0   0  0 25  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0   0 Inf
           USC00020750 1964    10   31 0   0   0  0 0   0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0
           USC00020750 1964    11   30 0   5   0  0 0   0  0  0 0  0 91  0  0  0 36 94  0  0   0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0   0 Inf
           USC00020750 1964    12   31 0 107  20  0 0   0  0  0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 79 152  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0"), header = TRUE)

rainfall <- unlist(as.data.frame(t(raindf[1:3, -c(1:4)])), use.names = FALSE)
rainfall <- rainfall[!is.infinite(rainfall)]
rainfall[rainfall > 0] <- 1
rainyruns <- rle(rainfall)
rainyrunsDf <- data.frame(lengths = rainyruns$lengths, values = rainyruns$values)
rainyrunsDf <- subset(rainyrunsDf, values != 0)
rainyrunsDf <- rainyrunsDf[order(rainyrunsDf$lengths, decreasing = TRUE), ]
rainyrunsDf[1,1]
## [1] 4
```